# Calculate angle between skew vectors

Tags: symbolic, vector

I want to use Mathematica to calculate the angle between two vectors (say `a` and `b`) that don't lie in the same plane. The vectors are of the same length (156) have a dot product with a unit vector that's normal to a plane that their projections lie that's the same (90). Their projection vectors onto this plane are denoted by `p` and `q` respectively. The angle between `p` and `q` is 120 degrees.

```
$Assumptions = 
  (a | e) ∈ Vectors[3, Reals] && e.e == 1 && a.e == b.e == 90 && 
  Sqrt[a.a] == 156 == Sqrt[b.b]; 
p = a - (a.e) e;
q = b - Dot[b, e] e;
Simplify[TensorExpand[a.b], Sqrt[a.a] == 156 == Sqrt[b.b]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should also include `b` in your assumptions!

```
$Assumptions = (a | b | e) ∈ Vectors[3, Reals] && e.e == 1 &&a.e == b.e == 90 && a.a == 156^2 == b.b;
p = a - (a.e) e;
q = b - (b.e) e;
```

Now the condition concerning `p.q` can be evaluated

```
cond=Simplify[TensorExpand[p.q == Sqrt[p.p] Sqrt[q.q] Cos[120 °]]]
(*18 + a.b == 0*)
```

Knowing `a.b`you can evalaute the angle between a,b!

```
cosα = (a.b/Sqrt[a.a b.b] /. Solve[cond, a.b][[1]]) 
(*-(18/Sqrt[a.a b.b])*)
```

Comment: Does the 1 in Solve[cond, a.b][[1]] refer to in[1] the global conditions? I am struggling with mathematica with these in[] as I can not reset the number (to get in[1] for that line) and the result  does not show numerically as it is not using the lengths of a and b in the final line of code.

Comment: No! Without `[[1]]` Solve returns double  list-brackets.

Comment: I don't know why Mathematica doesn't simplifies the result `-(18/Sqrt[a.a b.b])` completely.